# Laravel 5.6: session()->push('variable') doesn't reach middleware until second refresh

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I noticed that in Laravel 5.6, my session variable isn't passing to my middleware until the second page refresh. If I redirect to a page, the session does pass to the view on the first attempt, however in my instance I need to pass the content to the view.

Has anyone else noticed this and have a solution?

**Middleware:**
Let's say you have this middleware called **ViewData** that shares variables to the view.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        $setHandle = session('setHandle')[0];

        $account = AccountUser::where('handle', '=', $setHandle)->first();
        view()->share('account', $account);

    return $next($request);

}
```

**Controller:**  The Controller sets the setHandle session variable then returns a view:

```
public function add()
{   
    $setHandle = 'abcd'; 
    session()->forget('setHandle');
    session()->push('setHandle', $setHandle);
    return view('account.add');
}
```

**Reference in my View**  My view will then have a reference to variables from this middleware.

```
      <a class="navbar-brand brand-logo text-light" href="{!! url('account/'.$account->whatever) !!}">{!! $account->whatever !!}</a>
```

The problem is the first return view is returned with the old setHandle variable, when I refresh again it returns the new account with the setHandle variable.

I thought it may have to do with where my middleware is set, but my viewData middleware is being set after the StartSession middleware, so I thought the session would be refreshed after the middleware is called.

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
'App\Http\Middleware\ViewData',
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: The session is initialized by the time the `add()` function in your controller, which means any change to the session in that function will not be able to be accessed in the view until you refresh (which is what you are experiencing). There is no way I know around this other than moving the session logic to a middleware or using an alternative method (i.e. Cookies or passed variables from Controller to View).

Comment: @BigScaryDuck this is exactly what I expected.  I was hoping there was another way to trigger the middleware ahead of the view being returned.